# How to show the vim theme in its original colors using iTerm

Tags: macos, vim, iterm

I have a Linux box,.  I use "Konsole" application. Inside "Konsole" the original colorschemes for Vim always show up right. They are not limited by the color palettes defined by the Konsole. Anytime I change the Konsole colorscheme, the terminal Vim colors are left intact.

However, in iTerm I can never get the exact colors for the schemes. If I change the iTerm theme, the Vim colors get mixed up too.

Is there any way to show up the vim theme in its original colors using iTerm, the absolute colors?

```
:echo &t_Co
```

returns 256.

Comment: I'm confused are you trying to use a gui colorscheme in a terminal version of vim?

Comment: Consider this, I setup github theme in command line vim. Then if I change the iTerm colorscheme, the Vim  colorscheme changes with this. When I used "Konsole", changing the theme of Konsole did not affect the command line Vim in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently asked [a similar question](https://superuser.com/q/604589/42141) which got migrated to superuser. My problem was that `white` actually gave me grey.

In my console there was a colour palette and [X11 colour names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11_color_names) were actually mapped to a position on the palette. Changing the palette changes the colour, the meaning of X11 White is rendered according to palette location 16 in my case.

Comment: Yes I think we are basically having the same problem. Thanks for your response. I am marking this as answer because I think this is as good as it gets!